# Are there problems accessing a microSD card via SPI when there are other slave SPI devices?

Tags: spi, sd, microsd

I'm working on a design that has a CPU with only one SPI port.  I have multiple (3) slaves connected to this port, one of which is a microSD card.

[Here is a report from an engineer](http://www.benjamin-kaminski.com/?p=96) who says that SD cards are designed to operate as the only slave to an SPI master.

Has anyone else been able to use a microSD along side other SPI slaves on the same bus?  Perhaps this report was just based on a particular, problematic miniSD card?

Would anyone recommend gating the SPI CLK line with the Slave Select line that goes to the miniSD card, just to be safe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this page](http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html) SD cards drive and or release the DO line synchronously with the sclk line:

> In the SPI bus, each slave device is selected with separated CS
>   signals, and plural devices can be attached to an SPI bus. Generic SPI
>   slave device drives/releases its DO signal by CS signal asynchronously
>   to share an SPI bus. However MMC/SDC drives/releases DO signal in
>   synchronising to the SCLK. This means there is a posibility of bus
>   conflict with MMC/SDC and any other SPI slaves that attached to an SPI
>   bus. Right image shows the drive/release timing of the MMC/SDC (the DO
>   signal is pulled to 1/2 vcc to see the bus state). Therefore to make
>   MMC/SDC release DO signal, the master device must send a byte after CS
>   signal is de-asserted.

So just sending a dummy byte to the SPI after raising the CS line high should work.  The site above has a timing diagram of the SPI bus when raising the CS line high on the SD card.

Also, it is a good idea to make sure that on power-up/card-insertion the microcontroller negotiates the use of SPI mode with the card.  These details can be found [here](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/Part_1_Physical_Layer_Simplified_Specification_Ver_3.01_Final_100518.pdf)

In summary, it should be OK to share the SPI bus with multiple peripherals as long as the above precautions are taken.

Comment: Great resources, Justin. Thanks!  I hope that will be all I need to do to handle slave conflicts with SD.